# why am i getting forbidden error in only one post Route?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, csrf

i am getting the CSRF forbidden error .
However csrf is working fine in the rest of the application like post route of logout,signUp,Signin deleteing anything e.t.c/.
But when i perform the post action in only one route "/addProduct"
i got the error
Note that i am generating my CSRF token before routes declaration.
I am attaching the main file code and the front end code of  addProduct.

[here is my main file code where i am generating token and including it in all routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54k9E.png)

```
app.use(csrfProtection);
app.use(flash());


// USed to include token and isLoggedIn information to render in every page
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.isLoggedIn = req.session.isLoggedIn;
  res.locals.csrfToken = req.csrfToken();
  res.locals.user= req.session.user;
  next();
});



// app.use((req, res, next) => {
//   // throw new Error('Sync Dummy');
//   if (!req.session.user) {
//     return next();
//   }});

app.use(multer({ storage: fileStorage,fileFilter:fileFilter }).single('image'));

app.use(shopRoute);
app.use(authRoute);
app.use('/admin',adminRoute);
app.use(errorController.get404);
```

[This is the front end code for ADD_Product.ejs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEv18.png)
here  i am including hidden input as well...
to get csrf value back to check it...

```
   <form action="<%=path%>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" value="<%=product.title%>" >

      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="price">Price</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" name="price" value="<%=product.price%>">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">

        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1" name="image" value="<%=product.imageUrl%>">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Description</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" name="description" value="<%=product.description%>"></textarea>
      </div>


      <% if (path=="/admin/edit") { %>
        <input type="hidden" name="productId" value="<%=product._id%>">
        <% }  %>

        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken %>"> 
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg center">+ </button>
```

Comment: Please post the code as text and not as an image.

Comment: uploaded the code in text...